# Warning message using fancyhdr in Overleaf

Tags: fancyhdr

To whom it may concern:

I get the following warning message in Overleaf for the following lines of code:

```
Line 125 \fancyhead[RO,RE]{\thepage}
Line 126 \fancyhead[LO,LE]{\leftmark}

The package is specified at Line 5:

\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,amstext,amsfonts,lscape,color,array,cite,pdflscape}
```

How could I correct the following warnings:

Package fancyhdr Warning: \fancyhead's `E' option without twoside option is useless. Please consider using the` twoside' option on input line 125.

Package fancyhdr Warning: \fancyhead's `E' option without twoside option is useless. Please consider using the` twoside' option on input line 126.

Thank you.

Regards,

Gary

Comment: Welcome. // Follow the advice of the (first) warnings and use twocolumn option OR remove the E. // BTW, without knowing your code it's very hard to answer such out-of-the-blue questions, which more often than not lead to closing such questions ...

Comment: Basically, if the document isn't two-sided, don't use `\fancyhead[RO,RE]{\thepage}`, but `\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}`

Comment: Thank you Rmano, this answered my question.